# AIX and Subversion

Tags: software-installation, aix, subversion

Very basic question regarding AIX and Apache Subversion:  I need to install an Apache Subversion client onto an AIX 4.3 system.  (Yes, this is a rather old version of AIX; the story is too long and boring to relate here...)

As far as I can tell, there is no Red Hat Package manager installed there, so I assume that I will have to find a compiled binary of the Subversion client for AIX in some form other than an RPM package, or I will have to retrieve an RPM-packaged Subversion client and extract the compiled binaries from it.

This is based on the assumption that even a Subversion client compiled for a more recent AIX flavor (say 5.3?) will be usable under this older AIX 4.3 server.

How can I install a Subversion client onto an AIX 4.3 system?

Comment: Why do you want an RPM? The traditional solution would be to download and compile the sources.

Comment: You need a compiler for that. That's not a given on AIX. And if it was, you're looking at a compiler from 1999 or thereabouts (I'm assuming from the post that that box hasn't been maintained at all). Not trivial.

Comment: As @Mat has pointed out, I would need a compiler for that, and afaict, there's no C compiler on this machine. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get an RPM install from IBM's AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications, for AIX 4.3.3 (nothing older than that).

You should read the [README.aix433](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/README.aix433) (ftp link) - that will walk you through installing RPM itself. Also install at least that and the base "ezinstall" package group.

Once you've got that, you can try installing an RPM for a more recent version of AIX (you'll find some for 5.1) - not guaranteed to work at all, the C library versions aren't the same, but you have a tiny chance.

The other option is try to compile SVN from source. Install the "app-dev" ezinstall package to get a compiler and a basic toolchain, and go for it. Not very likely to work out-of-the-box, you most likely will need to tinker a bit.

And please consider upgrading, you're a bit behind the times there :-)

Comment: Many thanks, @Mat.  And, fwiw, I would indeed upgrade this server, if I had any say in the matter...

Comment: Upgrade to 5.1, it'll simplify a million things and no one will notice (probably!) ;)